# ode version for gazebo 8

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello! Which ODE version is used to build gazebo?
Can't find the dWorldSetQuickStepInertiaRatioReduction function anywhere.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15796/ode-version-for-gazebo-8/) by [eugene-katsevman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3168/eugene-katsevman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 163 on 2017-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo uses it's own fork of ODE, which hasn't been synced with upstream in a while. [Here's the code](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/20229b3a94252b177973f5d82239a686d9ab00bf/deps/opende/?at=default).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1